# One hot coding in Train Validation and Test set (Production data)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-encoding, data-preprocessing, pandas

For example I have below  train set.

```
   name     values
0  Tony      100
1  Smith     110
2  Sam       120
3  Shane     130
4  Sam       140
5  Ram       160
```

After one hot encoding it becomes

```
    values   0    1    2    3    4   
0   100      1    0    0    0    0
1   110      0    1    0    0    0
2   120      0    0    1    0    0
3   130      0    0    0    1    0 
4   140      0    0    1    0    0
5   160      0    0    0    0    1
```

Now suppose i have test data in production with below levels of name :-

> Danny is new level in the cat var

```
   name     values
0  Shane      200
1  Danny      210
2  Sam        220
3  Tony       180
4  Danny      150
```

After one hot encoding of this

```
    values   0    1    2    3    
0   200      1    0    0    0 
1   210      0    1    0    0
2   220      0    0    1    0
3   180      0    0    0    1
4   150      0    1    0    0
```

I have few question based on above situations :

1. How to deal with new entry of level or value of categorical variable in production test data?
2. How to maintain input feature size for model(for above example it was 6 in training and 5 in test data) ?
3. Also tony was feature 0 in train ser however in test it is feature 3 does it impact prediction of test input from trained model?

Comment: Can you clarify (in the question) the motivation behind one-hot encoding these values (e.g. there are some sort of catalog code classification instead of some measurement readings)?

Comment: @B.Liu I got the answer for my question on SO. Check here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901180/one-hot-coding-in-train-validation-and-test-set-production-data/66901826#66901180]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use encodings learnt from training data to encode test data. So, you shouldn't *re-encode* your test set. This answers your second and third questions I believe.

> 1. How to deal with new entry of level or value of categorical variable in production test data?

For this one, you have options:

- try to obtain a more expressive train data to at least include a few samples from the categories that were only present in the test set
- if gathering data is not possible, i.e. you may always see new values in the production data, the encoding will be all zeros, another way of saying that this sample's label is *other*. But, adding the *other* category explicitly may be useful in some algorithms as well.
- Increase your frequency of retraining your models so that you don't encounter this very often, and deal the encounters as per the second bullet-point